# PlacePicker.getPlace() is deprecated

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to develop an application based on google place API. When I try to use

```
Place place=PlacePicker.getPlace(data,this);
```

there is an error showing `getPlace()` is deprecated.
Please suggest a solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google is tracking the interest in having a Place Picker widget here: (Android) https://issuetracker.google.com/128304810, (iOS) https://issuetracker.google.com/128304760. Please fill the linked form with your use case and needs if you are interested.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlacePicker#getPlace%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) states

> **This method is deprecated.**
>   Use `getPlace(Context, Intent)` instead.

You should find this information in Android Studio as well.

Comment: For those who didn't realise (like me), the Context and the Intent have been switched, so if you have a deprecation warning, switch the variables over.

Comment: why didn't they just change the implementation of the original function with the same parameters order in later releases ?!

Comment: @tynn how to "find this information in Android Studio", when I click 'more' on the hint, it just say the current is deprecated, that's it, no solution.

Comment: @tynn the javadoc on android studio says nothing https://www.dropbox.com/s/ski1w4myqxfsbd5/Screenshot%202018-11-23%2015.53.49.png?dl=0 I am using java, or it is just available in Kotlin. I wonder because every time facing a deprecated method, I have to search on the doc from the internet. I would be great if I can found directly in AS. Thanks

Comment: @thanhbinh84 it looks like you don't have the _JavaDoc_ available. It's not related to _Kotlin_ or _Java_. Maybe _Google_ doesn't provide the docs. Maybe you're using a different repository. But since you have a clear question which is unrelated to this one here, you should consider asking it separately. You'll find more input like this.

Comment: @tynn if possible, please capture your screenshot, otherwise that's fine. Thanks anyway. I will post question then. :)